# How to get nohup proccess id in bash script

Tags: bash, process, nohup

I have a bash script to run a command via nohup, I need the proccess id in the script.

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohupResult=$((nohup mycommand > nohup.out &) 2>&1)
echo $nohupResult
exit 0
```

But the `$nohupResult` is null.

I tried also this:

```
nohupResult=`nohup mycommand > nohup.out &`
```

But the `$nohupResult` is null either.

If I run the command `nohup mycommand > nohup.out &` in shell, I will get some outputs like:

```
[1] 447019
```

But how could I get the process id in the script?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pid of the last background job is in `$!`

```
nohup mycommand &
pid=$!
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use:

```
echo $!
```

This should return the PID of the last started background process.